# Taking capture from webcam using C code

Tags: c, ubuntu, webcam, webcam-capture

I'm trying to take some captures from my webcam using C program on Ubuntu and I cannot use OpenCV for hardware problems.
I used this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 76800 // number of pixels (320x240 for my webcam)
int main() {
    FILE *camera, *grab;
    camera=fopen("/dev/video0", "rb");
    grab=fopen("grab.jpeg", "wb");
    float data[SIZE];
    fread(data, sizeof(data[0]), SIZE, camera);
    fwrite(data, sizeof(data[0]), SIZE, grab);
    fclose(camera);
    fclose(grab); 
    return 0;
}
```

compiling my code  `gcc -o snap cam.c` and running snap gave as a result the `grab.jpeg` file. But It appears that is not a jpeg format.
Is there any possibility to generate directly a jpeg file ?

Comment: I know that this is gentoo, but might [this](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-836218-start-0.html) help?

Comment: In your code you open the output file as `grab.raw` but in your description you say the result is `grab.jpeg` - a JPEG file has more information than just the pixels so are you sure that the size of 320x240 is accurate?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I wrote grab.raw by fault but in my code it's grab.jpeg. About the size yes i'm sure it's 320x240 for my webcam

Comment: Why do you use `float`? And how this could be jpeg this is raw pixel...

Comment: How to fix it to obtain a jpeg

Comment: jpeg is a compression method for images, you need a jpeg encoder. And each pixel is a rgb (each 8 bits, 24 bits total).